# Categories as main menu items and subcategories as nested lists

Tags: functions, menus, navigation, categories

I am new to WordPress and am trying to make my website.

Would it be possible to list categories and subcategories as a nested list with links in the main navigation menu.

What am i trying to achieve is something like this, but if possible to list only subcategories that have posts:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Ever figured this out?

Comment: Hi Kendall,
not sure if the best way, but I am using 
wp_list_categories( 'child_of=2&title_li=' ) and it works for me. Hope this helps.